# Show that no flow can have value exceeding $9$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $N$ be the network with source $u$ and sink $v$, where each are is label with its capacity.

[image]

a) Show that no flow can have value exceeding 9

b) Give an example of a flow $f$ on $N$ such that $val(f)=9$

My professor went through this very fast, so I don't think I can understand very well about flow. The number on the graph are the capacity of the arc, I know that the flow can't be bigger than the capacity, so for a), is it because the max capacity is from $x$ to $y$ and the biggest is $5+4=9$ so the flow of the whole network can't be bigger than 9? Why can't we have the max capacity be $5+3+2=10?$

For b) I know that $val(f)= f^+ -f^-= flowout - flow in$, but they only give me capacity, should I assume that the flow and capacity are the same?

Comment: The two edges going into $v$ have a total capacity of $5+4=9$, so no more than $9$ can flow into $v$.  For part (b), label each edge with a flow that is less than or equal to its capacity, so that every vertex but the source and sink has flowout=flowin.

Comment: so the max flow is just the sum of in degree of the sink?

Comment: @Diane : Not always.  It depends on the network.  See : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem

Comment: @vadim123: Don’t you mean the *minimum* capacity of a set of edges that disconnects the graph?

Comment: Just want to make sure I understand it correctly. I'm not sure I understand why flowout have to be equal flow in?   Can I just assign the flow between zero and the capacity of the arc, like in the picture. So $X=\{a,x,b\}$ then $val(f(X))=9$?

Comment: @Diane: You have $3$ units flowing into $a$ and $7$ flowing out, which isn’t possible.

Comment: oh, so that what vadim123 means by saying flowout =flowin, I will fixed my graph and check back later

Comment: @Diane: Yep. Think in terms of flowing water: you can’t get more water out of a junction point than you have flowing in. You also can’t have more coming in than flowing out, because there’s no provision in this setup for reservoirs at the nodes.

Comment: I think it should look ok now, so the flow from $u$ to any vertex that is not $v$, has $val(f)=9$, Am I correct?

Comment: @Diane: Looks good to me.

Comment: yesss, Thank you very much, you guys teach much better than my professor.

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif, I'm sure if you spent an hour in a private conversation with your professor about this problem, you would get at least as much out of it as you did here.